# Teechart for Silverlight embedded

Tags: teechart

How can I integrate Teecharts in Silverlight embedded?
The normal Silverlight isn't useable, and the pocket Version is only for Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Steema has not tested TeeChart for NET with Windows Embedded Compact 7. Although applications for that environment can be built with the NET framework Steema not prepared any specific Compact 7 ready assembly.

Thanks,